# Case insensitive search with M-x find-grep-dired

Tags: grep

I’m trying to do a case insensitive search with `M-x find-grep-dired`. When I enter `M-x find-grep-dired` and hit `ENTER` and enter the directory name I get the prompt `find-grep (grep regexp):`. I understand this as “enter grep and then regexp”. So, for grep I enter `-i` for case insensitive search, and for regexp I enter the search word. But this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second prompt is asking you for just a "grep regexp", i.e. a regexp conforming to `grep` syntax  [1]. If you look at the implementation of `find-grep-dired` (`C-h f find-grep-dired` and click on the file link), you'll see that it uses `find-grep-options`, so you can add `-i` to the value of that variable. You can do that by asking for help on the variable (`C-h v find-grep-options`) and then clicking on the `Customize` link.

EDIT: if you don't want to change the value of `find-grep-dired` permanently, you can use the standard lisp facility of binding a variable temporarily with `let`:

```el
(let ((find-grep-options "-q -i"))
   (call-interactively #'find-grep-dired))
```

That's a very general mechanism that is worth remembering and getting familiar with.

And you can of course package that in a command and bind it to a key if you want:

```el
(defun find-grep-dired-case-insensitive ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((find-grep-options "-q -i"))
      (call-interactively #'find-grep-dired)))

(define-key global-map (kbd "C-c z") #'find-grep-dired-case-insensitive)
```

Footnote:

[1]  There are other regexp syntaxes: e.g. `perl` regexp syntax is different in many ways from that of (basic) `grep`; GNU `grep` can use an extended syntax if you give it a `-E` option; `Emacs` has its own syntax for regexps. They are all similar in many ways, but differ in others. That's why the documentation of the function says to use a "grep regexp".

Comment: Thanks. I don’t see a file link to click. But I did, `C-h v find-grep-options` and on that screen I clicked “customize” and I got a screen with “Find Grep Options: -q". Do I need to change `-q` to `-i`? What does `-q` mean? I searched for “grep options -q” but nothing relevant resulted.

Comment: I found that `-q` means "Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected. Also see the -s or --no-messages option."

Comment: Correct: it's a `grep` option so you'll see it with `man grep` from a shell prompt. The documentation string of `find-grep-options` also shows this. Customize the variable to *add* `-i` to it (as I mention in the answer).

Comment: Ok. I added `-i` so now I have `-q` and `-i`, and saved and restarted emacs. But it does not work. The text I search has a capital letter "Abcd", so when I search for `Abcd` it finds it. But when I search for `-i abcd` it does not find it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I added a screen shot showing that options changed to `-q` and `-i`

Comment: What do you mean by "when I search for `-i abcd`"? Are you typing the `-` at the regexp prompt? If so, don't do that: just type `abcd`.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Now it works. Thanks. So is it better to use the terminal to search with grep? In the terminal, I can specify for each search if I want case sensitivity or not. In emacs, now all search is case insensitive, correct?

Comment: Can you also explain `regexp conforming to grep syntax`? In the prompt I enter only regex, correct?

Comment: Modified the answer to add some explanation of the points you asked about.

Comment: "I don’t see a file link to click." means that you have an incomplete installation of Emacs (you are missing the `.el` files for the elisp sources).  My *guess* is that you're using a Debian-packaged emacs and need to `apt-get install emacs-el` (or something similar).

Comment: ...and if that's the case then you're almost certainly also missing the should-be-built-in documentation. You *should* have several manuals available via the Help menu.  If these aren't working, try `apt-get install emacs-common-non-dfsg` (or look up the correct name for that package for your particular OS/version).